# php fetching show empty data how it sovle

Tags: php, mysql

file uploading then am choose 
 only notice but my file path is automatic load am not want to load my path how it possible

and then am fetching my database show my file path only am not want show my code path so am not choose any file am choose only **NOTICE** text how it possible [enter link description here](http://sadanandtailors.com/website/)

```
my code
-------
t>
        <?php 

 $alert = ( isset($_REQUEST['alert']) ) ? trim($_REQUEST['alert']):'';


 $im=$_FILES['image'];
 $rnd = rand(1,1000);
 $path = "../home_image/";
 $im_name = $rnd."_".$im['name'];
 $fullpath =$path. $im_name;
 $value_fullpath = empty($fullpath) ? null : ($fullpath);





if($im['error']==0)
{
  if($im['type'] == "image/jpeg" or $im['type'] == "image/gif" or $im['type'] == "image/png")
    {
  copy($im['tmp_name'],$fullpath);

    }
    }



 $imp=$_FILES['imagep'];
 $rnd = rand(1,1000);
 $path = "../home_image/";
 $im_name = $rnd."_".$imp['name'];
 $fullpathp=$path.$im_name;
  $value_fullpath = empty($fullpath) ? null : ($fullpath);

if($im['error']==0)
{
  if($im['type'] == "image/jpeg" or $im['type'] == "image/gif" or $im['type'] == "image/png")
    {
  copy($imp['tmp_name'],$fullpathp);

    }

       }






    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))

    {


  echo $sql="INSERT INTO `home_page`(`slider_image`,`notice`,`prtofolio`) 
                        VALUES ('$value_fullpath','$alert','$fullpathp')";


 echo $query=mysqli_query($conDB,$sql) or die (mysqli_error());
 header('location:homepage_show.php');


    }






?>



        <table width="687" id="rounded-corner" summary="2007 Major IT Companies' Profit" >
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="myForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return(validate());">

          <tr>
            <td> slect slider image</td>
            <td><input type="file"  name="image"cols="60" rows="2"></textarea></td>

          <tr>

          <tr>
            <td> notice for home page </td>
            <td><input type="text"  name="alert"cols="60" rows="2"></textarea></td>

          <tr>

          <tr>
            <td> protofolio  </td>
            <td><input type="file"  name="imagep"cols="60" rows="2"></textarea></td>

          <tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td></td>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/></td><td></td>

          </tr>
        </table>
        <div class=""> <span class="disabled"> </span> </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end of right content--> 
    </div>
    <!--end of center content -->
enter code here
```

Comment: It must be hard, debugging that code. It would be easier if you align it properly, so you can just see the flow in a glance.

Comment: Have you read? [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)